# блог на django не публикуется на pythonanywhere

Tags: html, python, linux, ubuntu, django

Публикую свой блог на *Django*, на хостинге *Pythonanywhere*. Статические файлы собрались, *migrate* сделала.

В wsgi:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog'  # use your own username here
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application())
```

*Django = 1.8*

*Python=3.4*

В итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?  Подскажите.

пытаюсь выполнить wsgi построчно. ошибки не выдает и только после добавления последней строчки  application = get_wsgi_application() выдает следующие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А логи следующие:

```
   2016-04-30 13:39:10,006 :Error running WSGI application
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
raise e
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
raise e
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
raise e
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
raise e
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 179, in <module>
application = load_wsgi_application()
   File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 175, in load_wsgi_application
return __import__(os.environ['WSGI_MODULE'], globals(), locals(), ['application']).application
   File "/var/www/nitrogen987654321_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
 File "/home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog/qblog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup()
 File "/home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog/qblog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
 File "/home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog/qblog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
 File "/home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog/qblog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
 File "/home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog/qblog/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
 File "/home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog/qblog/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Comment: Ну а какой-нибудь журнал ошибок в админке есть?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: добавила логи...

Comment: Знаю что уже прошло 4 года, но для тех, кто будет гуглить такую же проблему.
Посмотрите финальные этапы настройки
https://studygyaan.com/django/host-django-website-application-for-free-in-5-minutes

Answer (score 3):

Настройка UWSGI – самый ошибкогенерящий этап [публикации из туториала ДжангоГёрлз](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/deploy/), так что не переживай.

Во-первых, в настройках есть ссылки на логи, посмотри, что в них. Скорее всего там написано, что не так.

Во-вторых, проверь, что структура файлов на сервере соответствует тому, [что должно быть](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/deploy/#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pythonanywhere).

В третьих, в файле с uwsgi-конфигом есть переменная `path`, стоит проверить, что имя пользователя в ней верное. Самый простой способ – выполнить в консоли `ls /home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog`.

Comment: "Настройка UWSGI – самый ошибкогенерящий этап публикации туториала ДжангоГёрлз, так что не переживай." - с чем это связано?

Comment: Чёрт его знает. Это эмпирическое наблюдение.

Comment: выполнила ls /home/nitrogen987654321/my-first-blog....    выдал:   __pycache__   activate.fish     db.sqlite3       easy_install      markdown_py  pip3.4         python3    requirements.txt  templates
activate      activate_this.py  django-admin     easy_install-3.4  pip          python         python3.4  site1             wheel
activate.csh  blog              django-admin.py  manage.py         pip3         python-config  qblog      .                                    путь правильный

Comment: Не совсем. Согласно структуре, рядом с `manage.py` должна быть папка `mysite`, а её нет (см. выдачу `ls`). Об этом же говорит ошибка: `No module named 'mysite'`.